# Python and sqlalchemy: How do I get the statement in a .to_sql call

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When a sqlalchemy *.to_sql statement has an error with out a try-except, the errant statement is printed to the console.

I want to catch that error statement and send it to a logger.  What is the value in logger.error() that will return the error reason, and errant statement?

```
 try:
        a.to_sql(name="lar", schema="lar", con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
 except sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError:
        logging.error(sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError)
        break
```

Without the try block, the console gets: (which is what I want in the logger)

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 
'Exempt' for column 'combined_loan_to_value_ratio' at row 1")

[SQL: INSERT INTO lar.lar  .... etc., ....
```

Comment: `.to_sql` is a `Pandas` function that wraps SQLAlchemy code, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions that inherit from [DBAPIError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError), such as `DataError` possess attributes `orig` and `statement` that contain the original DB-API error message and the SQL statement being executed, respectively.  So you can log like this:

```py
try: 
    a.to_sql(...)
except sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError as ex:
    logger.error('%s \n %s', ex.orig, ex.statement)
```

Producing a log message like this:

```
ERROR:mylogger:(1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'foo' for column `test`.`t75264888`.`ltv` at row 1") 
 INSERT INTO t75264888 (ltv) VALUES (%(ltv)s)
```

Comment: Sorry @snakecharmerb for taking this long to try this.  IT WORKED !  Thanks !